# ASP.NET MVC 4 Login using a hardware certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, certificate

My team is working on a new big project in which the level of security must be very high.

I'd like to know if it is possible to allow users to login using a certificate (hardware) and how to implement it (ASP.NET MVC environment).

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This question seems a bit too broad to me, could you try to narrow it down?

Comment: This application should be to be to authorize users to log in in 2 ways. Simply with a password and an email (weak authentification) or 'just' using a usb key, having an hardware certificate inside (strong auth). Generally the key is delivered by 3skey, certeurope, ect..